# Boostsrap toggle switch to keep value after refresh

Tags: javascript

With toggle switch on I want to change my background color and text color. 
How can I save the state when page refresh

```
        <script>
    document.getElementById("switch1").onclick = function() {
      myFunction()
    };

    function myFunction() {
      let color = document.body.style.background;
      if (color === 'black') {
        document.body.style.background ="white";
          document.body.style.color = "black";


      } else {
          document.body.style.background = "black";
          document.body.style.color = "white";

      }

    }
  </script>

    <form>
      <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="switch1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="switch1">Dark Mode</label>
       </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this. Each time you run the function, we'll update a key stored in local storage called 'darkMode', and then simply check this key when the webpage is reloaded

Snippets don't work with localStorage, so [here is a CodePen](https://codepen.io/_Light/pen/yLybZZQ) I made quickly to demostrate

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('darkMode') === 'true') {
    // Black Background
    document.getElementById("switch1").checked = true;
    document.body.style.background = "black";
    document.body.style.color = "white";
  } else {
    // White Background
    document.body.style.background = "white";
    document.body.style.color = "black";
  }
});

document.getElementById("switch1").onclick = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  let color = document.body.style.background;

  if (color === 'black') {
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'false');
    document.body.style.background = "white";
    document.body.style.color = "black";
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'true');
    document.body.style.background = "black";
    document.body.style.color = "white";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store this values in somewhere. One option to do this is [browser's local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage). But it does not work in old browsers.

To do this first you need to save the values of background color and color on the localstorage and then, on page load you call a function that apply the storage value to this properties.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("switch1").onclick = function() {
      myFunction()
    };

function myFunction() {
  let color = document.body.style.background;
  if (color === 'black') {
      document.body.style.background ="white";
      document.body.style.color = "black";
  } else {
      document.body.style.background = "black";
      document.body.style.color = "white";
  }

    // Add the new values to the localstorage
    localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', document.body.style.background);
    localStorage.setItem('color ', document.body.style.color);

}

// Now just call this function after page load.
function getStyles() {
  var currentBgcolor = localStorage.getItem('bgcolor') | 'white';
  var currentColor = localStorage.getItem('color') | 'black';

  document.body.style.background = currentBgcolor;
  document.body.style.color = currentColor;
}
```

```
<form>
  <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="switch1" />
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="switch1">Dark Mode</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: is it possible with $_session?

Comment: $_session runs on server side. You can use it too, but only if you are sure that you always will have one one server responding to yours clients requests. And using $_session requires that you do an ajax call from your frontend to your backend to set the variable.

Comment: Even that is feasible I don't recomend. Your should avoid use session on any programming language.

Comment: Maybe in this case session is better. If this value is persisted in some kind of user settings object, you can put that in your session and use that information to have the checkbox set.

Comment: I usually avoid keep values in memory on the server. It has many side effect that should be analysed carefully.